# Discord.py Rainbow Embed

Tags: python, discord.py

Im creating a Rainbow Embed command but i don't really know how it should work. Maybe you can look and help me create the command :D

Here the code

```
@bot.commands()
async def rainbowembed(ctx, *, message):
    embed = discordEmbed(description=message)
    ctx.send(embed=embed)
    for i in range(5):
        # On this point i dont know what to do...
        # I want to switch the color of the embed in this format
        # 0x3755ff, 0x13ff00, 0xff7400
        # and i want to repeat it 5 times, so it goes 5 times trough this Colors...
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: To start off, in the embed variable, you have to also pass in the title, so it wouldn't be: 
`embed = discordEmbed(description=message)` 

Rather: 

`embed = discordEmbed(title=title, description=message)`

Comment: No its a Neccesary i dont have to do title=

Comment: Ok, but do you get any error messages or is it just not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

Simple rainbow embed that changes color every 0.1 second:

```
@client.command()
async def rainbow(ctx): 
    
    cols = [0x32a852, 0x3296a8, 0xb700ff, 0x9232a8, 0xa8326f, 0xf25207, 0x3efa00, 0xfa0000]
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "RAINBOW",
        color = random.choice(cols)
    )

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    for i in range(1000):
        embed2 = discord.Embed(
            title = "RAINBOW",
            color = random.choice(cols)
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await msg.edit(embed=embed2)
```

After 1000 times embed does not change color anymore.

Comment: Are you sure editing a message 10 times per second will not get you API banned?

Comment: I saw many bots with rainbow embeds, and I only heard that only rainbow roles, nicknames are banable.

Comment: You will get rate limited for editing messages every 0.1 second probably

Comment: Yes this embed changes like 10 times every 0.1 second then there is 1 second break

Answer (score 0):

This is possible however be warned that you can get API limited if overusing this.

Import the modules:

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
```

Initialize the client and assign `colours` and `delay`:

```
client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
colours = [0x3755ff, 0x13ff00, 0xff7400]
delay = 1
```

Create a command:

```
@client.command()
async def rainbowembed(ctx, *, message):
```

Create and send the embed:

```
    embed = discord.Embed(description=message)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Iterate through each colour 5 times editing the embed every `delay` seconds:

```
    for i in range(5):
        for colour in colours:
            await msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(description=message, colour=colour))
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

Run the bot:

```
client.run("bot_token")
```

**References:**

- [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)
- [`discord.Message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=sleep#asyncio.sleep)